# "Explanation or submission guidelines" missing

Tags: nodes, 8

In editing a content type on a Drupal 8 site, I added text to the *Explanation or submission guidelines*, but when I surf to the node create/edit form, the text is nowhere to be seen.

Is this a bug, or are there extra steps involved that aren't documented in the UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That information is displayed in the help block. Make sure the theme you are using on those pages has a help block.

The Seven theme does have that by default, but either you've configured the node add/edit pages to use the front page theme, or you removed the help block.

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the "Help" block in your administration theme block layout.
Keep in mind that you need to have the Help module enabled to have the "Help" block available

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Drupal 8, you currently may have to clear caches to see this text in the help block.